# Postgresql: Why SET col = MAX(col2) doesn't work

Tags: sql, postgresql, set, sql-update, max

I wrote a code in postgresql that works in a select statement but not in an update one...
I don't understand why it doesn't work and how to do. Here's my code:

```
UPDATE netflix_tt_serie
SET total_num_parts = MAX(num_parts) OVER(PARTITION BY num_title)
```

With those columns:

```
num_title: 11 222 33333 444
num_parts: 12 123 12345 123
```

So the result I want (and it is the one I get in a select statement) should be:

```
total_num_parts: 22 333 55555 333
```

(I added space when num_title changed here just to be clearer) Thank you a lot for your help!!

Comment: Avoid data inconsistency, create a view instead.

Comment: It is really unclear how your results are calculated from the sample data.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in multiple ways.  A typical method is:

```
UPDATE netflix_tt_serie nts
    SET total_num_parts = max_num_parts
    FROM (SELECT num_title, MAX(num_parts) as max_num_parts
          FROM netflix_tt_serie
          GROUP BY num_title
         ) x
    WHERE x.num_title = nts.num_title;
```

Your syntax is not allowed because SQL in general does not allow aggregation functions or window functions in `UPDATE` statements.

Comment: Super cool it works !! Thanks a lot :D
(I saw your "unclear" flag on my question, sorry for that it was my first post)

Comment: @TristanTHOMAS . . . The question itself seems pretty clear (which is why I provided an answer).  The problem is that the sample data is not clear and I can't figure out what it is supposed to mean.

Comment: Ok got it! I'll be clearer if I'll post another one :)